# Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init…]' via Analyzer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, loadnibnamed

When i test my code via Analyzer then got:

> Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of [(super or self) init…]

My code:

```
self = [super init];//initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) 
{
    tickerSymbol = [object valueForKey:@"TickerSymbol"];
    url = [object valueForKey:@"URL"];
    rssFeed = [object valueForKey:@"RSSFeed"];

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClientInfoView" 
                                                             owner:nil 
                                                           options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ClientInfoView class]])
        {               
            self = (ClientInfoView *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
    [self.clientNameLabel setText:[clientObject valueForKey:@"Name"]];
    [self.symbolLabel setText:[object valueForKey:@"TickerSymbol"]];

    //[self loadHistoricalInfo];
    self.getStock = [GetStockValue stockValueWithDelegate:self];
    [self loadInfo:object clientObject:clientObject];
    [self layoutLabels];

}

return self;
```

Comment: Why are doing this: `self = (ClientInfoView *)currentObject;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            self = (ClientInfoView *)currentObject;
```

That doesn't make any sense.  You should never be re-assigning `self` save for to the result of `[super init...]` (and in the case of some advanced techniques, which this isn't).

You should also never need to grub through the IB file like that.  Create an outlet and make a connection, then use the outlet directly in your code.

Note that, in general, you shouldn't load interface in `init` methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `self = (ClientInfoView *)currentObject;`. I think there's some confusion as to how to connect to your object from within your `nib`. Instead of instantiating an object within the nib file and trying to swap your object for it, try connecting to `File's Owner` from within your `nib`, and then set yourself as the owner:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClientInfoView" 
                                                         owner:self 
                                                       options:nil];
```